# how to export jqgrid into excel from struts2 web page

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2

sorry I am new in stack overflow, so I don't know how to post struts2 jsp webpage, but my problem is I am created grid by using j query i want export that grid into excel sheet. how i will do by using struts,j query,jqgrid.

**It is my JGrid code**

```
<script>


    function exportExcel()
    {
        var mya=new Array();
        mya=$("#sample_grid").jqGrid('getDataIDs', {});  // Get All IDs
        var data=$("#sample_grid").getRowData(mya[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
        var colNames=new Array(); 
        var ii=0;
        for (var i in data){colNames[ii++]=i;}    // capture col names
        var html="";
        for(i=0;i<mya.length;i++)
            {
            data=$("#sample_grid").getRowData(mya[i]); // get each row
            for(j=0;j<colNames.length;j++)
                {
                html=html+data[colNames[j]]+"\t"; // output each column as tab delimited
                }
            html=html+"\n";  // output each row with end of line

            }
        html=html+"\n";  // end of line at the end
        alert(html);
        document.forms[0].csvBuffer.value=html;
        document.forms[0].method='POST';
        document.forms[0].action='csvExport.jsp';  // send it to server which will open this contents in excel file
        document.forms[0].target='_blank';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

> `<s:url id="loadGrid" action="loadGrid" namespace="/"/>`

```
<sjg:grid  href="%{loadGrid}" 
                gridModel="gridModel" 
                caption="Grid Sample" 
                navigator="true" 
                navigatorAdd="false"
                navigatorDelete="false"
                navigatorEdit="false"
                navigatorRefresh="false"
                navigatorSearch="false"
                navigatorView="false"
                pager="true"
                 navigatorExtraButtons="{
                        add : {
                        caption : 'Export to Excel',
                            title : 'Export to Excel',
                            icon : 'ui-icon-save',
                            onclick: function() {
                                exportExcel();
                            }
                        }
                    }">
<sjg:gridColumn title="Name" name="name" align="left"/>
<sjg:gridColumn title="City" name="city" />
<sjg:gridColumn title="Country" name="country"/>
<sjg:gridColumn title="Credit Limit" name="creditLimit"/>
```

`</sjg:grid>`

**I am not getting html values in alert inside function()**

Comment: have you succeded ? I need the same thing can you share some code ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',{view:true, del:false, add:false,
 edit:false, excel:true})
            .navButtonAdd('#pager',{
                            caption:"Export to Excel", 
                            buttonicon:"ui-icon-save", 
                            onClickButton: function(){ 
                              exportExcel();
                            }, 
                            position:"last"
                        });

    function exportExcel()
    {
        var mya=new Array();
        mya=$("#list").getDataIDs();  // Get All IDs
        var data=$("#list").getRowData(mya[0]);     // Get First row to get the labels
        var colNames=new Array(); 
        var ii=0;
        for (var i in data){colNames[ii++]=i;}    // capture col names
        var html="";
        for(i=0;i<mya.length;i++)
            {
            data=$("#list").getRowData(mya[i]); // get each row
            for(j=0;j<colNames.length;j++)
                {
                html=html+data[colNames[j]]+"\t"; // output each column as tab delimited
                }
            html=html+"\n";  // output each row with end of line

            }
        html=html+"\n";  // end of line at the end
        document.forms[0].csvBuffer.value=html;
        document.forms[0].method='POST';
        document.forms[0].action='csvExport.jsp';  // send it to server which will open this contents in excel file
        document.forms[0].target='_blank';
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

JSP:-

Ref this link :-
    http://www.vaannila.com/struts/struts-example/struts-export-jsp-to-excel-example-1.html

Comment: hi Lawren , thanks for your answer but can u tell me what is list , pager,navGrid.
I have all data in j grid how i will export into excel.

Comment: Hi,Lawren I got the data in excel but problem is I am not getting Header row. because my header is not in list. see my last four line code.